# Calling a function in gtk's calllback funtion

Tags: c++, static, callback, gtk

Been stuck for a couple of days with a problem. I was forced to learn c++ for a project assignment which included gtk. I've manged to program the windows that I want and most og the functionality but I can wrap my head around how to solve storing data from callback function!

*Before I continue, I just want to add that I've search the net for answers but haven't stumbled upon same issue. I know that I can't call a function from the static callback function*

Anyhow, 3 primary classes (among others) are involved:

- Window - Only responsible for widget, and writing to the buffer.
- Keyboard - Has a loop which listens to user inputs and also updates status messages, reads from the buffer.
- Buffer - The user adds data in the buffer. The Window class should be able to write to the buffer and Keyboard should be able to read.

At a certain point, when running the program, a user will want to input new coordinates. The Keyboard listener hears when the specific button has been pressed and within the class, a Window class function is called and input dialog is displayed.

```
Window *window; //Header
....
void Keyboard::GetInputCoord(){ //.cpp
    window->display();
}
```

*window is referenced in the Keyboard.h and linked in the main class like this :*

```
....
keyboard.window = &window;
keyboard.buff_read = &buff;
window.buff_write = &buff;
....
```

I have in the the Window class, display(), manged to send an array of my entries to the static callback function but now I'm having trouble figuring out how to send this to my Buffer? I tried calling a function from the same class, but useless...

```
static void entry_coord(GtkButton *widget, GtkWidget **entry)              
{                                                                          
    GtkWidget *entry_x_in = entry[0];                                 
    GtkWidget *entry_y_in = entry[1];                                  
    const char *x, *y;                                                 

    x = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(entry_x_in));                     
    y = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(entry_y_in));                     

     // write_buff(x, y); <- something like this
}
```

Since I cannot call this function that I have declared in the the Window.h and implemented in .cpp what options do I have ? Is there any work-arounds?

*Edit 10th January 2015*

Window.h

```
#ifndef def_Window
#define def_Window

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

#include "Buffer.h"

using namespace std;

class Window
{
    public:
            Window();
            void display();
            void write_buff(const char, const char);

            Buffer *buff_write; //Sound maybe be in private
    private:

};
```

Buffer.h

```
#ifndef def_buffer
#define def_buffer

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

#define BUFF_ROW    10
#define BUFF_COL    2

using namespace std;

class Buffer
{
    public: 
            Buffer();
            void write_to_buffer(string msg);
            void read_from_buffer();
   private:
            int front, back, size, count;
            string buffer[][];
};
#endif
```

Keyboard.h

```
#ifndef def_Keyboard
#define def_Keyboard

#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

#include "Kinematic.h"
#include "Window.h"
#include "Buffer.h"

#define MSG 10

using namespace std;

class Keyboard
{
    public:
            Keyboard();
            void UpdateMessages();
            void SetStatus(string msg);
            void SetMessage(string msg);
            string messages[10];
            int indexMsg;
            string statusString;
            ....

            Window *window;     
            Buffer *buff_read;

   private:
};
```

I've tried multiple ways of writing to the buffer. I've tried calling the Buffer function write_to_buffer() and I've tried calling from Window function write_buff() which calls write_to_buffer. The compiler says the the functions are not declare in this scope.

Comment: What happens if you try to call `write_buff()` like that? Can you provide at least your header files?

Comment: I've edited the first post

Comment: Is `entry_coord()` part of the `Window` class? If not, you'll need to somehow give a `Window` to it so that you can call `write_buff()`, which is a method on `Window`.

Comment: Well, it still needs to be a static function, that is the problem. I want to send values to the Buffer from the callback function BUT I cannot call another function from a static without creating new instance of my object. But doing so will deference the current buffer from main?

Comment: Will it maybe work if I made the write_to_buffer function in Buffer.h static and that way I can call on it from anywhere?

Comment: No, making `write_to_buffer()` static in this case means you would need to specify which buffer to write to somehow. What languages are you familiar with, since you say you are still learning C++?

Comment: Mostly Java and little C.

Comment: Another thought...What if I create a struct in Window where I have entries and a reference to Buffer which I pass in the callback function?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by making the userdata pointer for `entry_coord()` something that allows you to access everything you need in that function. Your idea of a struct that has pointers for entries and the buffer will certainly work but it seems to me that your Window class should work just as well... Just use `this` as the data pointer and make the callback look something like this:

```
static void entry_coord(GtkButton *widget, gpointer data_ptr)
{
    auto window = static_cast<Window*> (data_ptr);
    window->update_buff_from_entries();
}
```

Then your Window class naturally needs to contain (private) pointers to the entries so that the new public method `update_buff_from_entries()` can get values from them and call `write_buff()`.